How to create hover effect with a transparent white background on mouse hover for an image button in WPF?
I have created an image button that contains a canvas inside. I want to add a transparent white color to the background of this button when the mouse hovers.
I have the following code for the button:
<Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"
        Width="30"
        Height="30">
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Uniform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Canvas Height="512" Width="448">
            <Path Fill="White" Data="M224 0c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32l0 19.2C119 66 64 130.6 64 208l0 18.8c0 47-17.3 92.4-48.5 127.6l-7.4 8.3c-8.4 9.4-10.4 22.9-5.3 34.4S19.4 416 32 416l384 0c12.6 0 24-7.4 29.2-18.9s3.1-25-5.3-34.4l-7.4-8.3C401.3 319.2 384 273.9 384 226.8l0-18.8c0-77.4-55-142-128-156.8L256 32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zm45.3 493.3c12-12 18.7-28.3 18.7-45.3l-64 0-64 0c0 17 6.7 33.3 18.7 45.3s28.3 18.7 45.3 18.7s33.3-6.7 45.3-18.7z" />
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>

I created a separate style dictionary as Styles.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ImageButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.2" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

The output is not my desired result. When the mouse hovers, no effect is applied. How can I fix this?

I see that you define the Background property at the Button level:
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0" />
    </Button.Background>

Instead, you should define this property at the level of your Style:
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ImageButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            White
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

